# Cant get Authorized with my API that has a JWT authentication Im Working With Xamarin

Tags: c#, django-rest-framework

Well Im new in `Xamarin` and I'm developing and App, the authentication is `JWT` based.
Im using a `HttpClient` and setting the `AuthenticationHeaders` but It always returns `Unauthorized` when I try it on `Postman` it Works but I can't make it work in my app.

Here is how im trying to do it:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("JWT", accessToken);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase);
var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", servicePrefix, controller);
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone here to try and help without knowing what API you're trying to authenticate to. You should provide more context/info.

Comment: Try the answer below based on documentation: `For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal "Token", with whitespace separating the two strings.` - e.g. `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`

Comment: Yeah in postman I send the Authorization like This
Authorization: JWT <TOKEN>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format($"{<yourURLString>}", string.Empty));
            var jsonTransport = "";
            var jsonPayload = new StringContent(jsonTransport, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "JWT " + accessToken);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, jsonPayload);
            string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

then deserialize the responseContent to your object using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
Note: Below are code samples, edit to your own objects

```
SubscriptionResponse profileResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubscriptionResponse>(responseContent);
```

then if your method returns something, use the return statement. Something like this

```
return profileResponse.Data.Subscriptions;
```

Comment: I Try this and nothing happened :( Maybe because That URL doesn't accept POST

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a get, this could be a guide

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format($"{<yourURLHere>}", string.Empty));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "JWT " + accessToken);
var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(uri);
var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

then deserialize your string response
Note: this is a sample - edit to your model (You may use PostMan to get the response format in JSON and model it in C#)

```
var UserDetailResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetail>(responseContent);
return UserDetailResponse;
```